# How to allow only the author of the article in the Django UpdateView to access the article update page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to allow only the author of the article in the Django UpdateView to access the article update page?

```
#views.py
class ArticleUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'articles/update_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'article_update'
    form_class = ArticleForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['securities_types_list'] = StocksETFsBonds.objects.all()
        context['tags_list'] = Tag.objects.annotate(articles_quantiy=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')).order_by(
            '-articles_quantiy')[:10]
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `get_object` and check if the requesting user is the author of the article (you did not provide the details of your models, so i will presume that your `Article` model has a `author` field):

```
class ArticleUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'articles/update_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'article_update'
    form_class = ArticleForm

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj.author != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return obj
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['securities_types_list'] = StocksETFsBonds.objects.all()
        context['tags_list'] = Tag.objects.annotate(articles_quantiy=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')).order_by(
            '-articles_quantiy')[:10]
        return context
```

You can also implement `ArticleUpdate.get_queryset` (if the requesting user is not the author of the article they receive a 404 error):

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Article.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```